# Angular: google maps works first time then blank on mobile screens only

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm building a mobile app using ionic/angular the page I have created has a google map that works fine on first load/access but when navigating back then back again the map page the map gets blank or not rendering!!

This issue happens on mobile sizes only! and if I did touch or click anywhere gets working again but not on initialization as screenshot down shows.

Here's a `stackblitz`  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-angular-8-start-template-xx3btx?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab2%2Ftab2.page.ts

Just click on the button on the home page `click here` you will see that works fine the first time, So just navigate back by the button under the title ( don't use the back for **stackblitz** ) then go to the page again and you will see that the map went all blank.

There are no errors showing on console;

My code:

```
@ViewChild('map', { static: true }) mapElement: ElementRef;
map: any;

activeLocation: any;
```

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.loadMap();
}
```

```js
loadMap() {

    this.loadingService.present('Loading, please wait...');

    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.2865163, 47.9916857);

    let mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    var marker, i;
    let th = this;

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map, 'resize', function () {
      google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, 'resize');
    });

    this.wooService.kefanBranchesLocations().then(
      locations => {

        this.loadingService.dismiss();
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]['lat'], locations[i]['lng']),
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: this.map
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
              th.activeLocation = locations[i];
              th.activeLocation['open_hours'] = typeof th.activeLocation['open_hours'] == 'string' ? JSON.parse(th.activeLocation['open_hours']) : th.activeLocation['open_hours'];
              console.log(th.activeLocation);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div #map id="map"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#map {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**A screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Look for an error message in the browser's console log.  ("Developer screens.")

Comment: No errors at all; this only happens on phone screen sizes!!

Comment: I noticed that your sample code contains your API key. Please note that it is best practice to keep your API keys private and when sharing sample codes, please make sure that you restrict them properly per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `AfterContentInit` and move your code from `ngOnInit()` into `ngAfterContentInit()`.

Angular won't have created the map element at the init stage. You need to check later in the page lifecycle.

Check the official docs for more info: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks.

Comment: I tested on `AfterContentInit ` and `AfterViewInit` and at least `OnInit` all are the same the map getting working at the first time then just blank and no errors on the console or the terminal so I'm not racing myself, and what more weird in this it's happening on phone screens only and if I touch the screen and move the map gets working and rerendering again just like the gif above

Comment: Are you using OnPush change detection?

Comment: I don't know what's OnPush so I think I'm not!. What make me more confusing this issue happens on mobile devices only or on the browser if I activated the mobile mode only, so working fine if I just resize the browser to whatever,

Comment: What happens if you add `console.log(this.mapElement.nativeElement)` just before `this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);` in ngOnInit()? Does it exist? If you're on mobile and you can't access dev tools, you could always try printing something to the screen to debug the existence of the element at this point.

Comment: Can you provide a simple stackblitz that recreates the problem?

Comment: I'm debugging on the browser no problems, I tried that it consoling the `div`, no problems but the desktop div map content `HTML` is different than the mobile one it's a lot less like the mobile map version is missing a lot of components and when I try to touch the map it get that missing content and `rerender` ( that scenario happens after first time only )

Comment: here's the `stackblitz` with the same issue I have https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-angular-8-start-template-xx3btx?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab2%2Ftab2.page.ts just clcike on `click here` button and go to map will work fine then back and click again will show you the blank page.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Map loads fine the first time. 2nd time it shows only markers. Touching anything makes the map re-appear.

Comment: For me (and I see in your stackblitz, you as well) I was using a back button.. and this is what is breaking it. If i replace that with a menu button and use the menu to go to a new page and then use menu to go back to the map - it works fine.